# Compare two columns from two tables and return SUM of matches

Tags: mysql, sql, database, compare

I am working on a project where I have to compare two tables together and sum the number of occurrences. For this example I will use name as the key that I would like to compare. I have used Union all and Count(*) but it wouldn't give me the desired output.

### Table apple

```
+----+-------+---------+
| Id | Name  | Surname |
+----+-------+---------+
|  1 | Adam  | Jaxon   |
|  2 | Adam  | Brixton |
|  3 | Brian | Simpson |
|  4 | Adam  | Steper  |
|  5 | Brian | Bastion |
+----+-------+---------+
```

### Table orange

```
+----+-------+---------+
| id | name  | surname |
+----+-------+---------+
|  1 | Adam  | Thompson|
|  2 | Brian | Coach   |
|  3 | Jhon  | Sinded  |
+----+-------+---------+
```

There is one name match for Adam and one match for Brian so the desired output I would like to receive is

```
+-------+
| Total |
+-------+
|  3    |
|  1    |
+--------+
```

The query that I am using similar to the person who had answered the question however there are few changes. Unfortunately this only returns number of matches for each name

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM
(
SELECT Name
FROM 
apple
UNION ALL
SELECT 
NAME
FROM
orange
) as named
GROUP BY name



+----------+
| Count(*) |
+----------+
|   2    
|   3
+----------+
```

Comment: There are three Adam in table apple and two Adam in table orange. Will be this be considered as count 1 ?

Comment: Come on. Show us some effort.

Comment: why `surname` not considered?

Comment: @rocks Must be - how else could the result be 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it, grouping and count name:

```
SELECT 
    id,
    name,
    surname
    count(1) as total
    FROM
    (
        SELECT 
            id,
            name,
            surname
            FROM apple
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 
            id,
            name,
            surname
        FROM orange
    )
GROUP BY name
```

UPDATE

To SUM all results before your query:

```
SELECT sum(total) 
FROM (
        SELECT 
            id,
            name,
            surname
            count(1) as total
            FROM
            (
                SELECT 
                    id,
                    name,
                    surname
                    FROM apple
                UNION ALL
                SELECT 
                    id,
                    name,
                    surname
                FROM orange
            )
    GROUP BY name
)
```

Comment: This does what my sql query did before however changing union to union all gives correct number of matches. The only thing is I need the numbers SUMed.

Comment: I change to my answer, you can sum your count before your query result, basicly, I add a new select with sum the last query count

Answer (score 0):

No DB server available, so haven't tested it - should do the trick, however:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM
(
    SELECT DISTINCT apple.name FROM apple
        JOIN orange ON apple.name = orange.name
);
```